# React-native-sound: setSpeakerphoneOn doesn't work

Tags: react-native-sound

I looked up documentation for setSpeakerphoneOn at https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/API, where it states that you just need to pass a boolean value into it. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a toggle button for switching on and off setSpeakerphoneOn for voicemail files.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
...
  play = async () => {
    if (this.sound) {
      this.sound.play(this.playComplete)
      this.setState({playState: 'playing'})
    } else {
      const { id, userCredential, contentUrl } = this.props
      const voiceMailURL = `${contentUrl}/content/voicemail/get?msgId=${id}&token=${userCredential.access_token}`
      this.sound = new Sound(voiceMailURL, '', (error) => {
        if (error) {
          Alert.alert('Notice', 'audio file error. (Error code : 1)')
          this.setState({playState: 'paused'})
        } else {
          this.setState({playState: 'playing', duration: this.sound.getDuration()})
          this.state.useEarPiece ? this.sound.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) : this.sound.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)
          this.sound.play(this.playComplete)
        }
      })
    }
  }
  playComplete = (success) => {
    if (this.sound) {
      if (success) {
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Notice', 'audio file error. (Error code : 2)')
      }
      this.setState({playState: 'paused', playSeconds: 0})
      this.sound.setCurrentTime(0)
    }
  }
 toggleUseEarPiece = () => {
    this.setState({
      useEarPiece: !this.state.useEarPiece
    })
  }
render () {
...
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        {this.state.playState === 'playing' &&
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginHorizontal: 20}} onPress={this.pause}>
                          <Icon color='#000' name='ios-pause' size={20} type='ionicon' />
                        </TouchableOpacity>}
                        {this.state.playState === 'paused' &&
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginHorizontal: 20}} onPress={this.play}>
                          <Icon color='#000' name='md-play' size={20} type='ionicon' />
                        </TouchableOpacity>}
                      </View>
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleUseEarPiece}>{speaker}</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to giggle, but this line in your code may be at fault:

```
this.state.useEarPiece ? this.sound.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) : this.sound.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```